# How to send notification when the app is closed? (android java)

Tags: java, android, notifications

Im making a reminder app that's based on location.
One of it's main features is to send the user a notification when he is close to one of the locations he set.

I've tried and searched the web, but still couldn't find a way to send a notification - when the app is closed (e.g. the user force closed it (not force stopped!)).

I've come across the idea of `foreground service` - which isn't bad, but has one problem - it HAS to send a notification when it is started.

I want the notifications to be like most apps' notification - for example, instagram just sends a notification that a message has been received. There's no notification saying that a service has started.

If someone knows a way - please, tell me. I'm lost :)

Im sorry for not including code. Everything i've tried so far isn't relevant - I need ideas.

Comment: If you're using geofencing to notify of when you're close (please tell me you're not using normal location updates for this) this is all handled for you.  It notifies a BroadcastReceiver, which can put up a notification  https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing

Comment: hmm im not yet using anything to notify when a user is close... but this seems interesting.
I haven't using geofencing yet (i have a feature in my app to get the current location, which uses normal location upadtes...) but I'll try to use it now with notifications. Many thanks.

Comment: Wait, will this also work when the app is closed?
How can I make it so?
Do i still need to use a service?

Comment: You just register for a geofence.  That's all.  The system will wake you up and call your BroadcastReceiver when needed.

Comment: Will the broadcast receiver work even if the app is closed? all I have to for example, is register geofences for location the user adds?

Comment: Im storing the locations in the database. If the user deletes a location i guess I have to "deregister" the geofence as well? Im sorry for asking so much question - but im not quite sure :( - can you link me to some kind of basic tutorial? Thr android developer's one is kinda messy and I didnt find any other good ones....